# Use one if() instead of multiple observeEvent() to display message in a shiny app

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, observers

I have the shiny app below in which I use three observers which are activated based on the actionbuttons. I was wondering how I could replace those observers with an if() that would include all 3 conditions inside.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h2("Sweet Alert examples"),
  actionButton(
    inputId = "success",
    label = "Launch a success sweet alert",
    icon = icon("check")
  ),
  actionButton(
    inputId = "error",
    label = "Launch an error sweet alert",
    icon = icon("remove")
  ),
  actionButton(
    inputId = "sw_html",
    label = "Sweet alert with HTML",
    icon = icon("thumbs-up")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$success, {
    sendSweetAlert(
      session = session,
      title = "Success !!",
      text = "All in order",
      type = "success"
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$error, {
    sendSweetAlert(
      session = session,
      title = "Error !!",
      text = "It's broken...",
      type = "error"
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$sw_html, {
    sendSweetAlert(
      session = session,
      title = NULL,
      text = tags$span(
        tags$h3("With HTML tags",
                style = "color: steelblue;"),
        "In", tags$b("bold"), "and", tags$em("italic"),
        tags$br(),
        "and",
        tags$br(),
        "line",
        tags$br(),
        "breaks",
        tags$br(),
        "and an icon", icon("thumbs-up")
      ),
      html = TRUE
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just call a helper function to do what you want after you get the event

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$success, {sendMessage("success")})
  observeEvent(input$error, {sendMessage("error")})
  observeEvent(input$sw_html, {sendMessage("sw_html")})

  sendMessage <- function(type) {
    if (type=="success") {
     sendSweetAlert(
        session = session,
        title = "Success !!",
        text = "All in order",
        type = "success"
      )
   } else if (type=="error") {
      sendSweetAlert(
        session = session,
        title = "Error !!",
        text = "It's broken...",
        type = "error"
      )
   } else if (type="sw_html") {
     sendSweetAlert(
        session = session,
        title = NULL,
        text = tags$span(
          tags$h3("With HTML tags",
                  style = "color: steelblue;"),
          "In", tags$b("bold"), "and", tags$em("italic"),
          tags$br(),
          "and",
          tags$br(),
          "line",
          tags$br(),
          "breaks",
          tags$br(),
          "and an icon", icon("thumbs-up")
        ),
        html = TRUE
      )
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: basically I want to avoid the fact that observers require an argument "expr". so I would like to get rid of them totally

Comment: What does that mean? How do you want the observing to take place with out an observer? I'm not sure what you are after.